# lambda calculus as a type theory

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

From the Introduction section of Homotopy Type Theory book:

> Type theory was originally invented by Bertrand Russell ... It was later developed as a rigorous formal system in its own right(under tha name "$\lambda$-calculus").

Can anyone explain me this sentence? I'm having trouble seeing $\lambda$-calculus as a type system.

(also in the same paragraph, $\lambda$-calculus called as "Church's type system")

Comment: While it may not seem obvious, the book "Types and Programming Languages" by Benjamin C. Pierce explains this in detail by going from lambda calculus up to a simple typed programming language. See: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9548/268

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the very next paragraph of that book (see [HoTT](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/), p. 2) they give an informal characterization of what qualifies a language system (or logic) as a type system, namely that: *in it all terms are typed*.

By "Church's type system" they're referring to the **simply typed lambda calculus** (introduced in 1940).

> In 1930s, in particular while preparing his negative solution to the decision problem, Church had introduced a system of **untyped lambda calculus**. This, of course, was *not* a type theory.

The 1940 system, however, is a type theory, because in it all terms are typed (see, for example (T&S), Section 1.2 for how exactly this is done). By "lambda-calculus as a type system" they're referring to this second, simply typed version of lambda calculus.

(T&S) Troelstra, A.S. & Schwichtenberg, H. *Basic Proof Theory*, 1996.